# Return error to user if user enter wrong option in Python Tree

Tags: python, binary-tree

i am totally new in Python, i try to do a simple code whereby if the user entered a wrong Product code, he will get an "error message" and he will be prompted to enter again. But i just cannot get it to work. Can somebody help. Thanks

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self,val,key,Number):
        self.val = val
        self.key = key
        self.number = Number
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def search(value,p):
    if(p.val == value):
        print("You bought item:",p.val,",description:", p.key,"cost:", p.number)
        return 1
    else:
        if(p.val !=None):
            if(p.val < value):
                search (value,p.right)
            if(p.val > value):
                search (value,p.left)
        else:
            print("You've entered a wrong option")

root = Node(3,"Chips", "$12" )
root.left = Node(1,"Chicken", "$13")
root.left.right = Node(2,"Potato","$14")
root.right = Node(5,"AisKrim","$15")
root.right.left = Node(4,"Bag","$16")
root.right.right = Node(6,"TV","$17")

option = int(input("Please enter code:"))
answer = search(option,root)

while (answer != 1):
    print("You've entered a wrong option")
    option = int(input("Please enter code:"))
    answer = search(option,root)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a couple issues.  First, you need to handle the case where p is not defined in search to avoid an exception.

```
def search(value,p):
    if p is None:
        return None
```

Adding that code to the beginning of the search function will avoid the basic exception that happens when searching fails and you reach a Node that doesn't exist.

Second, the recursive code should return values.  So you need to change the else clause to something like:

```
else:
    if(p.val !=None):
        if(p.val < value):
            return search (value,p.right)
        if(p.val > value):
            return search (value,p.left)
    else:
        print("You've entered a wrong option")
```

Note that each call to the search function returns the value from the recursive call.

Comment: Well, I did run the code with just these three lines changed before I posted and it was working fine to print "You've entered a wrong option" for missing items, and the data for found items.

Answer (score 0):

Working code below. Thanks djkrause!

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self,val,key,Number):
        self.val = val
        self.key = key
        self.number = Number
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def search(value,p):
    if p is None:
    return 1

elif(p.val == value):
    print("You bought item no:",p.val,", the description", p.key, "and the cost is:", p.number)
else:
    if(p.val !=None):
        if(p.val < value):
            return search (value,p.right)
        if(p.val > value):
            return search (value,p.left)

root = Node(3,"Chips", "$12" )
root.left = Node(1,"Ayam", "$13")
root.left.right = Node(2,"Itik","$14")
root.right = Node(5,"AisKrim","$15")
root.right.left = Node(4,"Kentang","$16")
root.right.right = Node(6,"Itik","$17")

option = int(input("Please enter code:"))
answer = search(option,root)

while (answer == 1):
    print("You've entered a wrong option")
    option = int(input("Please enter code:"))
    answer = search(option,root)
```